# logo wont show on any of my the wordpress theme

Tags: contextual-help

So I'm using oceanwp theme. I upload a logo and it wont override the original logo. So I decided to switch themes. Same issue. My uploaded logo won't show.

my site:

www.magnagoldenhealing.com

Comment: Where are you uploading the logo? Many themes have you go into the Customizer, under Site Identity, to use whatever logo you upload.

Comment: I did that. Unfornately, it didnt work.

Comment: TY so much for your help. I got it resolved.

Comment: Hey Magna Scholar, 
It would be nice to share the solution with us. 
Because I have the same problem.

Nice website of yours, by the way. ;-)

Thank you.